# Como adicionar input dinamicamente após segundo cabeçalho em tabela

Tags: jquery, html

Estou com um problema, gostaria de inserir inputs dinamicamente em uma tabela com mais de um cabeçalho, em meu script ao clicar na imagem de `+` as linhas estão sendo adicionadas após o primeiro cabeçalho mas não na sequencia, ou seja, nas linhas seguintes ao segundo cabeçalho, bem como deletar as linhas do primeiro cabeçalho e também do segundo.

Coloquei um exemplo no JSFiddle, vejam:

https://jsfiddle.net/t5soaubu/

Tentei fazer uma alteração nesse trecho de código inserindo a class `linhas`, mas sem sucesso:

```
    <tr class="linhas">
  <td><input type="text" name="rg[]" style="text-align:center" id="rg[]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="endereco[]" style="text-align:center" id="endereco[]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="municipio[]" style="text-align:center" id="municipio[]" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="uf[]" style="text-align:center" id="uf[]" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode deixar como alvo o segundo header colocando uma classe específica:

### HTML

```
<tr class="segundoHeader"> ... </tr>
```

### Javascript

```
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");

    novoCampo = $("tr.segundoHeader:first").clone();
    novoCampo.find("input").val("");
    novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.segundoHeader:last");  

    removeCampo();
});
```

---

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/t5soaubu/4/

Comment: Olá @Lucas Costa, fazendo isso consigo inserir no segundo cabeçalho mas não no primeiro, a intenção é ser simultâneo, tanto no primeiro como no segundo, valeu pela dica, vou editar minha pergunta.

Comment: Olá @Lucas Costa, funciona na primeira interação, na segunda vez que clico no ícone de '+' as linhas estão sendo inseridas somente no segundo cabeçalho, valeu.

Comment: @LucasCosta se você clonar `.linhas` para `.segundoHeader` a partir do 2 click para adicionar `inputs` as 2 linhas serão adicionadas em `segundoHeader` como está acontecendo no seu exemplo

Comment: Clonei de `.linhas` para aproveitar o botão de remover @adventistapr. Atualizado.

Comment: Nossa, valeu @Lucas Costa e Leonardo Rodrigues, ficou show, mas preciso de mais uma ajuda que esqueci de colocar na pergunta, o possibilidade de remoção dessas linhas, pois ao clicar no ícone de '-' eu deleto as linhas do primeiro cabeçalho.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente ajuda.